# POST não está recebendo JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

Preciso de uma ajuda com relação à execução de um POST. **Pois quando tento chamar minha API (http://www.afectus.com.br/api/teste) para execução de um Post, não estou conseguindo passar o JSON para ela.**

Segue a API utilizada:

```
// POST: api/Teste
public void Post([FromBody]string json)
{
    ClassRetorno cr = new ClassRetorno();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
    {
        cr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassRetorno>("{\"Id\":1,\"Nome\":\"From Api\",\"Email\":\"post@fromapi.com\"}");
    }
    else
    {
        cr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassRetorno>(json);
    }

     mysql = new ClassMySQL();
     if (mysql.conectar())
     {
         mysql.insert("teste", "id, nome, email", cr.Id + ",'" + cr.Nome + "','" + cr.Email + "'");
     }
}
```

Resumindo: Se a string Json for nula ou estiver vazia, vai salvar no banco (Id: 1, Nome: From Api, Email: post@fromapi.com)

Se não, vai salvar conforme o parâmetro recebido.

Esse é o método que executa o Post:

```
public async Task Posting(ClassRetorno item)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://www.afectus.com.br/api/teste");
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "text/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Post executado!", "Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Post não executado!", "Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Se alguém souber a possível causa deste problema, ou no mínimo, puder dar alguma orientação, ficarei grato.

**Obs**: Usei a ferramenta Postman para testar a API e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Não ficou claro na pergunta o que exatamente não funcionou. Ocorre algum erro? Em que parte?

Comment: Você esqueceu de dizer qual é o problema...

Comment: Ok, obrigado. É que quando eu tento chamar minha api, passando um json para ela. É como se ela não recebesse esse json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receba o objeto `ClassRetorno` como parâmetro ao invés de `[FromBody]string json`, o `ModelBinding`resolverá o json que está chegando.

Comment: Muito obrigado Lucas. Confesso que tentei remover apenas o **[FromBody]**, deixando **string json**, porque imaginava que o post precisava receber necessariamente uma string.

Comment: Tive um problema parecido, coloquei apenas o objeto que gostaria de receber e o modelbinding do aspnet resolveu o Json que estava chegando